# How do I import a model from another app in Django?

Tags: python, django

So in my project `book_letter`, I have an app named `contents`. Inside it, I have a model named `Book`. As below.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And I have another app named `recommendation`, with a model named `Recommendation`. As below.

```
from book_letter.contents.models import Book

class Recommendation(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    source = models.ForeignKey("Book", related_name='book', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

However, when I run `python manage.py runserver`, I get an error saying

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'book_letter.contents'
```

I don't see what I've done wrong. Any ideas? Thanks :)

++ Directory tree (`synergy_django` is the project name. I referred to it as `book_letter` for sake of convenience.)
[image]

Comment: I think you don't have a `contents` folder in your `book_letter` app. can you send your directory tree, please?

Comment: @SirSaleh I've added the tree. Thanks :)

Comment: did you use ```django-admin startapp``` to create the apps? just want to make sure you have an ```__init__``` file in each app directory

Comment: @twrought Yes, I created the apps with ```startapp``` command, and yes I have ```__init___``` file in each app directory. :(

Comment: I think `book_letter` app, probably missing the `__init__.py` and can't be recognized as a module. create it manually if it's not there.

Comment: @SirSaleh Oh you mean the project itself?

Comment: Django expects you to import this model by walking down all the way from your BASE_DIR - where is manage.py? share full directory tree

Comment: @twrought I've pasted the directory tree. The name of project is actually ```synergy_django``` not ```book_letter```. I've referred to it as ```book_letter``` for sake of convenience. :) Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to reference the project in your import if both of your apps are in the same project. You can simply import using `from contents.models import Book`